# Plotting multiple y variables over time using gglot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to figure out how to make a plot that has multiple y variables with x being the year.

`A`, `B`, `C` are the y variables that I want to plot against `Year`. `A`, `B`, `C` have a few different observations for each year.

Here is what I have so far:

```
ggplot(ABC, aes(Year)) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = A, colour = "A")) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = B, colour = "B")+ geom_line(aes(y = C, colour = "C")
```

This gives me a nice looking line graph, but it plots the line vertically through all of the values for each variable for each year. Instead, I would rather have it just plot the total value for each variable for that year.

Please let me know if you have any tips for how I can solve this!

*Extra brownie points if you can tell me how to include error bars! Thanks!

Comment: You need to reshape your data from wide to long, then you can reference A,B,C within a single variable.  There are plenty of examples on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I knew there would definitely be other examples of this, but it's hard to know what to search for when you don't know what you are doing. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ABC <- data.frame(A = rnorm(100),
                  B = rnorm(100),
                  C = rnorm(100),
                  Year = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), 
                                    as.Date('2009/01/01'), 
                                    by = "year"), 10))

ABC %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Year) %>% 
  group_by(Year, key) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Year, value, color = key)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]